# Rendering odditiy in Meteor when using Foundation5 Javascript Modules

Tags: javascript, meteor, zurb-foundation

I've been using Foundation5 with a new Meteor app, and the CSS is working fine for me.

But I've had some trouble properly arranging the javascript to use advanced features like the Orbiter slider.

I'm adding the Foundation javascript from the client/compatibility directory so that it doesn't get wrapped by Meteor.

Problems:

a. Foundation wants to be added to the `<body>` of the html because it initializes Fastclick, which expects the body element to exist.  I've simply commented out the fastclick initialization, and ensured that foundation loads after jquery and modernizr.  This seems to be adequate.  Is there a better approach that would allow the Fastclick initialization to occur?

b. At the end of the  tag is where Zurb says one should initialize the Foundation plugins using a jQuery call like:

```
$(document).foundation( -- settings objects -- );
```

I've tried simply putting the script block at the bottom of my main template, but this doesn't seem to work.  So there doesn't seem to be an effective way to do this right in the template. I guess the Meteor way is to to have such code reside in a Template.*.rendered function or in the helpers or someplace that triggers a reactive re-render of the template.

```
Template.layout.rendered = function () {
   $(document).foundation({
     orbit: {
         // options
     }
   });
};
```

So I've tried the Template.*rendered function and it works -- sort of.  In some browsers (webkit), the slider renders on the initial load of the page with the template. But not in Firefox.  I haven't tested IE.

But in all browsers, if I navigate within my meteor app (I'm using iron-router routes) to a page without the slider, and then back again, the slider doesn't render.  I've confirmed that the Template.*.rendered code with the orbit slider initialization is being called, and I can see it acting on the DOM elements in Chrome's developer views.

By complete chance, I resized my browser window and poof, the slider appears, and is working perfectly.  Sure enough, for all the browsers I'm using, a resize of the window is all it takes to make the slider appear.

I tried wrapping the template elements in {{#constant}} blocks -- no apparent changes.

I've now tried about 6 different ways I've found on StackOverflow and elsewhere to try and get the browser to redraw the DOM without any luck -- I'm guessing one of these would work if I could call it the right way at the right time, but even if it does, there really should be a way to avoid all this if I do it correctly.

So the DOM is on the page, the javascript is running and acting on the DOM, but I need to tell the page to actually draw the DOM.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Foundation 5 on my Meteor project as well.

Calling $(document).foundation() from the template.rendered event is the proper way to do it. Each time the DOM is redrawn by Meteor, foundation breaks. Sometimes features can get away without reinitiating foundation, but for everything to work it needs to be reinitiated. In your case, after re-executing $(document).foundation(), I think simply calling $(window).resize() should work:

```
    Template.layout.rendered = function () {
       $(document).foundation({
         orbit: {
             // options
         }
       });
       $(window).resize();
    };
```

Comment: It did, thanks.  All my searching for this simple answer came up with much more convoluted ways to get a redraw out of the browser.  As usual, a little JQuery goes a long way.  So every template render causes a Foundation re-initialization?  Or do you have a strategy to minimize that aspect of the problem?

Comment: Depends on your layout, but you could try localizing the reinitialization. For example if your Orbiter slider is contained inside one area, you could do $('#containerForOrbitSlider').foundation().

Comment: Also, you could choose to only reinitialize the orbit slider as opposed to all of Foundation using $(document).foundation('orbit', { /* options */ });. Or do a mix of the two.

Comment: lastly, if your orbit sliders are all contained inside one template, you could minimize the scope of the template.rendered event to just that template. Template.templateContainingOrbitSliders.rendered = function(){}.

Comment: I'm doing a combination of the last two you recommend.  Scoping the call to orbit, and calling it in the rendered callback for the specific template the orbiter is in.  Seems to work, but I need to experiment and see if multiple templates can contain different initializers, say for reveal or dropdowns.